# Which data saving method i use?

Tags: iphone, database, nsuserdefaults

Hi i am making an app which will save data(say... time,location ,etc) many times in a day

NOW i have to maintain full history of this...for months

SO i was asking which data saving type i use

sqlite database or NSUserDefault   (i am aware of only these 2)

or  is there any other method?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could abstract all of this away using Core Data. You are right that you still need to decide on which backing store to use (flat file, xml, sqlite).  xml is human readable which is good for debugging, but for the large amount of data you will have, sqlite will be much faster.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite is easy to everyone have some database knowledge.

Core data need much time to learn, but when you know it, use it is more easy than Sqlite.

NSUserDefault only use to save some small data, like configuration data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sqlite and core data for your database.

use of NSUserDefault is not proper in case of large database. NSUserDefault uses with little amount of data (such as passcode ).